# Revert throws "missing revert data" in inherited method

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I've got a base contract which I use to add functionality to other contracts by inheritance.

For some reason, neither `revert` nor `require` are working as expected when the method is called by a descendent which acquires the method via "is". eg `contract Sample is AttribChecker`

Here's part of the method in Attribchecker;

```
 function getAttribute(string memory attribName) public virtual view returns(string memory) {
        BindingCollection coll = BindingCollection(_bindingCollectionAddr);
        bool attrExists = coll.existsAttrib(attribName);
        console.log("attr exists?", attrExists);  //works as expected
        if (!attrExists) revert("no such attrib");  //when attrExists is true, fails here
        [...]
}
```

Instead of getting a normal revert message, I get this error:

`Error: missing revert data in call exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (error={"stackTrace":[{"type":4,"sourceReference":{"function":"getAttribute","contract":"SampleContract","sourceName":"contracts/Embeddable.sol","sourceContent":"//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense\npragma solidity ^0.8.0;\n\nimport \"./BKLibrary.sol\";\nimport \"./BindingCollection.sol\";\nimport \"hardhat/console.sol\";\n\ncontract Embeddable {\n    using BKLibrary for string;\n    \n    bool private _published;\n    string private _fqBinding;\n    address private  _bindingCollectionAddr;\n    address private owner;\n\n    modifier onlyOwner {\n        require(msg.sender==owner, \"onlyOwner\");\n        _;\n    }\n\n    constructor(address bindingColAddress_) (more...)`

I would like it to fail with the normal revert message so I can see that it failed because of "no such attrib" not all this other stuff.

Why is it failing with "missing revert data" on the call to revert?

Comment: Can you include all your smart contract code?

Comment: The code that is failing is shown in the question.

Comment: Sure, but I would to deploy it and retrieve error line and give you  the solution. But if you don't put all your smart contract code I cannot help you

Answer (score 0):

`require` takes a boolean, like so:

```
require(condition, error message);
```

So your check should look like this:

```
require(attrExists, "no such attrib");
```

But your problem is probably with the `coll.existsAttrib`. From the stack trace, it appears that the revert is caused by an external call. The only external call here is the `coll.existsAttrib`.

Comment: I'm using revert here, not require, since no need to run the test again.

Comment: Require is best practices for checks. Don't use an if statement with revert.

Comment: Well ok, but neither revert nor require are returning the revert message.  I've confirmed with ethers.js that there is some problem in the communication between hardhat and ehters   It's not a problem with existsAttrib itself which I've separately tested and works as expected. The failure occurs on the call to revert which I've been able to confirm with the logging output. (which is why, the by the way I use revert instead of require. )

Comment: Got it - hope you can get it sorted out!